# Determining our position relative to the sun

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Okay, I'm 63, and only went as far as precalculus in school, but that's probably enough to understand the answer. Here's my question:

Imagine a line passing through the center of the sun and the center of the earth. If you draw that line at all points in the earth's revolution around the sun* you have a plane the bisects the earth into two roughly equal half spheres.

*not factoring in the movement of the sun through the galaxy, etc.

At every place where that plane touches the surface of the earth, you have a "solar equator." If you draw a line that passes through the center of the earth perpendicular to that plane, then you have a "solar north pole" and a "solar south pole" on the earth -- points that are constantly moving on the surface of the earth.

Here's my question: My latitude is 43.53 North. But in this system I would also have a "solar latitude" which would be constantly changing. I would like to know my minimum and maximum "solar latitude" in the space of a year, and, more importantly, how much my "solar latitude" could change in a single 24 hour day.

This question came to me as I was pondering how the sun climbs and falls in the sky at an angle or in an arc.

I don't know how to figure that out. Do you?

Comment: The plane is the *ecliptic*; the perpendicular goes through the poles of the ecliptic. But the question is better suited to Astronomy StackExchange.

Comment: thanks, Matt :) ... and sorry, I don't know how to locate the astronomy stack exchange or how to move my question over there ... is there a link that explains that?

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: I'm sorry to see that there are close votes; it seems to me that this question should be fine here or at the astronomy site.   It's a cool question.

Comment: For the record:  I posted the above comment under the false impression that I was logged into physics.stackexchange.  I still think it's a cool question and would fit in great there (or at math.stackexchange) but did not intend to encourage leaving it open on MO.

Comment: Related to stuff like [Horizontal coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_coordinate_system) and [Position of the Sun § Declination of the Sun as seen from Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun#Declination_of_the_Sun_as_seen_from_Earth). The tilt of Earth's axis (wrt. the ecliptic) is about 23.44 degrees. So the maximal solar altitude you see at summer solstice (c. June 21st) is $90-43.53+23.44=69.91$ degrees, and the maximal altitude at winter solstice (c. December 21st) is $90-43.53-23.44=23.03$ degrees.

Comment: thanks, all ... and sorry for misplacing this in math